# rotate hdr map in three.js

Tags: three.js, hdr

i have set x-axis as up axis in my three.js scene. Now all env maps (hdr) are wrong oriented. How can I fix? I tried by rotating the hdr file, but that does not work.

```
this.pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer as any);
new RGBELoader().setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType).setPath('assets/').load('adams_place_bridge_1k.hdr', (texture) => {
  texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
  var envMap = this.pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;
  scene.background = envMap;
  scene.environment = envMap;
  texture.dispose();
});
```

Is there a workaround with cubemaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `r162` it is possible to rotate the scene's background and environment. To do so, you can configure [Scene.backgroundRotation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.backgroundRotation) and [Scene.environmentRotation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.environmentRotation). Both are of type Euler and represent the rotation in radians.

The following official example demonstrates this feature:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_envmaps

Side note: The usage of `PMREMGenerator` on app level is not necessary in latest releases anymore. Environment maps are internally pre-processed with `PMREMGenerator` if they are used with PBR materials or if you configure a blurry background via [Scene.backgroundBlurriness](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.backgroundBlurriness).